# How do I use ExpectedException in C++/CLI NUnit tests?

Tags: exception, testing, nunit, c++-cli, expected-exception

How do you do the equivalent of:

```
[Test, ExpectedException( typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException) )]
void Test_Something_That_Throws_Exception()
{
    throw gcnew ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Some more detail");
}
```

...in C++ (the example there is C#)? As far as I can see, there's no typeof() function for the C++ implementation of NUnit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid anyone else hunting around for ages trying to find it, here's the solution:

```
[Test, ExpectedException( ArgumentOutOfRangeException::typeid )]
void Test_Something_That_Throws_Exception()
{
     throw gcnew ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Some more detail");
}
```

Simply use the `::typeid` of the exception :-)