# How can I properly use ExpectedException attribute in C++/CLI?

Tags: unit-testing, c++-cli

The problem is that C++/CLI doesn't have a `typeof` operator. So how can I translate the following C# code to C++/CLI?

```
[ExpectedException (typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line that you are probably looking for:

```
[ExpectedException(ArgumentOutOfRangeException::typeid)]
```

The answer is taken from [How do I use ExpectedException in C++/CLI NUnit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102792/how-do-i-use-expectedexception-in-c-cli-nunit-tests) and you would have gotten it too if you did some searching online.

Comment: I actually figured it out. Thanks any though.